# Symfony2: unable to impersonate user when website log-in using two different user providers

Tags: symfony, impersonation, fosfacebookbundle

In my website user can log-in with simple account (created in my website, configured MY_OWN_USER provider, which selects user by email) or using facebook log-in (integrated through fosfacebook bundle).

When i'm trying to impersonate user (appending link '...?_switch_user=demo@demo.com', like described in [Symfony2 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#impersonating-a-user)) Symfony2 logs such warning:

**security.WARNING: Switch User failed: "The user is not authenticated on facebook"**

I've checked **Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\SwitchUserListener** and looks like by default it gets not MY_OWN_USER provider but fosfacebook provider which tries to select user by facebook_id (if i append link with '...?_switch_user=FACEBOOK_ID' - switch user works correctly!)

So how to make that SwitchUserListener would get MY_OWN_USER provider which selects user by email not by facebook id?

Comment: Ofcourse i could try to change SwitchUserListener that it would select user by email (not by username), but maybe there are other ways without changing Symfony2 source code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring impersonation in your firewall config in `security.yml`, you can specify which provider should be used to find the user who is being impersonated ([ref](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)).  For example:

```
switch_user:
    provider: MY_OWN_USER
```

Hope this helps!