# Symfony impersonation - separate firewalls and separate user providers

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, impersonation

I have a Symfony application with two firewalls, one for admins and one for normal users.

```
admin:
    provider: admin
    # etc

main_site:
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
```

I'd like admin users to be able to [impersonate](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/impersonating_user.html) normal users.  How can I do this, given that they're using separate firewalls and separate user providers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There were several things I had to do to get this to work.

**Context key:** As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17991481/328817), I had to give both firewalls the same context.  Without this, admins were taken to the login page when trying to switch users.

**Config on both firewalls:** I had to add the basic `switch_user` configuration keys to *both* firewalls:

```
switch_user:
    role: ROLE_ADMIN
```

If I just put the config on the `main_site` firewall, admins got an access denied message when *exiting* impersonation and going to an admin page. (For example, the route `/admin/dashboard?_switch_user=_exit` would give a 403).

**Provider key** on the `main_site`'s config:

```
main_site:
    switch_user:
        role: ROLE_ADMIN
        provider: fos_userbundle
```

Without this, I got the error "Switch User failed - user@example.com not found".  Digging into the code, it turned out that the `admin` user provider was being used, and of course the normal users couldn't be found when using that provider.

(`provider` key for `switch_user` config discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12916510/328817).)

Alternatively, I could have added this as a provider key for the firewall itself:

```
main_site:
    switch_user:
        role: ROLE_ADMIN
    provider: fos_userbundle
```

You'll see from the config in my question that `fos_userbundle` was only specified as a provider for `form_login`, not for `main_site` as a whole, which is why it wasn't being used until I added it.  Adding it in either place (impersonation config or whole firewall) would do the trick.

**Here's the full set of relevant config:**

```
admin:
    provider: admin
    # Have to put basic switch_user config on both firewalls
    switch_user:
        role: ROLE_ADMIN
    # Both the admin and main_site firewalls have the same context, to allow
    # cross-firewall impersonation
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/17991481/328817
    context: boardworks

main_site:
    form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
    switch_user:
        role: ROLE_ADMIN
        # Have to explicitly set the provider, otherwise the site will use the admin
        # user provider when looking up the users whom admins are trying to impersonate
        provider: fos_userbundle
    # Rather than adding the provider above, I could have added it here:
    #provider: fos_userbundle
```

Comment: Thank you. Putting both firewalls under same context fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, @shrty.  Glad it helped!

Comment: hey @Sam, i'm trying to do the same as you in this question but with the addition of different hosts (impersonating across hosts). Please check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153988/symfony-impersonate-across-different-hosts) and let me know if you come up with any idea... thanks!

Comment: Hi @rrubiorr81, I didn't know about the `host` option, I'm afraid.  Sorry not to be able to help!